# Return filename with wildcard

Tags: excel, vba

```
sFile = Dir(sPath & sFile)
Debug.Print sFile
```

`2022.txt` is returned if `sFile` (the active cell) contains `2022.txt`; how can I return the same if `sFile` contains `202*.txt`?

Comment: It doesn't already do that?  Are there other files in that folder which match that pattern - eg. `2021.txt` ?

Comment: `2022.txt` is the only file matching the pattern, but `Debug.Print sFile` returns nothing.

Comment: You may have forgotten the trailing backslash in `sPath`, e.g. C:\Test\ and/or the leading wildcard in `sFile`, e.g. `*202*.txt`: `sFile = Dir("C:\Test\*202*.txt")`. The 2nd `*` could be replaced with a `?` since it's one character you're replacing.

Comment: Thank you! I needed the leading wildcard: `sFile = Dir(sPath & "*" & sFile)`.